# AngularJS 1.2.28 or 1.3.8?

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting to learn AngularJS, the tutorials I follow use the version 1.2.28, and it's quite different from 1.3.8. So my question is, should I:

- Keep learning 1.2.28.
- Try to learn 1.3.8 the hard way?
- Wait for a new version?

I really don't know what to do!

Comment: If you have to support legacy browsers (IE8+) you have to stay with the 1.2 branch otherwise you can already use 1.3.8

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS 1.3 or AngularJS 1.2.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400419/angularjs-1-3-or-angularjs-1-2-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wait for the new version. See here a video on why:

http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/12/23/angularjs-1_3-1_x-angularjs-2_0-my-take

Angular 1.2.x would only be useful if you are targeting IE 8, and it's getting closer and closer to a dead end.

Your bet should be on the latest 1.x version. That's now 1.3.x and soon in ng-conf by end of January will be 1.4 (more about 1.4 at http://gurustop.net/newsletter/7)

The differences between 1.2.x and 1.3.x shouldn't be that big for someone starting. Mostly just new features and most heavy changes affect advanced users. The entire changelog is available at : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

There are several documentation improvements in 1.3.x as well.